NDSolve::litarg error and overdetermined system error in NDSolve
Before the long description about my problem, my question is  How can I avoid NDSolve::litarg error and overdetermined system error in a NDSolve for simultaneous differential equation.
Nowadays I tried to solve a simultaneous differential equation using NDSolve. 
My previous question here 

Important part of my code related to the problem is
(* Higgs Field *)
\[Mu]HT2[x_, f_] := \[Mu]^2 - 
   M^2 Cos[\[Phi][x]/f + \[Alpha]0] + (m\[Phi][x, f]*
      ch*(1.12*10^(-3))^2)/x;
h[x_, f_] := 
  If[\[Mu]HT2[x, f] >= 0, 0, Sqrt[-\[Mu]HT2[x, f]/\[Lambda]]];


(* Derivative Potentials for \[Phi] and h *)
Vd\[Phi][x_,f_] := (1/f)*((\[CapitalLambda]^4)*Sin[\[Phi][x]/f] + (M^2)*(h[x, f]^2)*
     Sin[(\[Phi][x]/f) + \[Alpha]0])
Vdh[x_, f_] := -(\[Lambda]/4) (h[x, f]^3);


(* Thermal Dissipation Rate *)
\[CapitalGamma]th[x_, f_] := 1.12 10^(-4) (m\[Phi][x, f])^(1/2) x^(-1/2);
\[Gamma]h[x_, f_] := Max[yt^4 (h[x, f])^2/\[CapitalGamma]th[x, f], \[CapitalGamma]th[x,f]*(yt)^2];

(* Equations of Motion for \[Phi] and h *)
EOM\[Phi][x_, f_] := 
  D[\[Phi][x], {x, 2}] + Vd\[Phi][x, f]/(m\[Phi][x, f])^2 == 0;
EOMh[x_, f_] := 
  D[h[x, f], {x, 2}] + \[Gamma]h[x, f]*D[h[x, f], x]/m\[Phi][x, f] + 
    Vdh[x, f]/(m\[Phi][x, f])^2 == 0;

(* Initial Conditions for Differential Equations *)
initialConditions[f_] := {\[Phi][xosc[f]] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][\[Phi]][xosc[f]] == 0.1, 
   h[xosc[f], f] == h0[xosc[f], f], 
   Derivative[1][h][xosc[f], f] == Derivative[1][h0][xosc[f], f]};

(* Numerical Solution of the Equations of Motion *)
solf1 = NDSolve[{EOM\[Phi][x, f1], EOMh[x, f1], 
    initialConditions[f1]}, {\[Phi][x], h[x, f1]}, {x, tinit[f1], 
    500}, DependentVariables -> {\[Phi][x], h[x, f1]}];


My problem is related to NDSolve::litarg error
NDSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in If[3600-9032.41 Cos[1.4 +\[Phi][<<1>>]/100000]+(4.349*10^-7 Min[169/1000,2.62599*10^7 Power[<<2>>]^(6/17)])/x>=0,0,Sqrt[-(\[Mu]HT2[x,100000]/\[Lambda])]] should literally match the independent variables.

After questioning about my problem, I tried to solve it and I found the problem referring to a few questions on Mathematica Stack Exchange. 
And finally, I found that problem cause by below terms. 
(* Initial Conditions for Differential Equations *)
initialConditions[f_] := {\[Phi][xosc[f]] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][\[Phi]][xosc[f]] == 0.1, 
   h[xosc[f], f] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][h][xosc[f], f] == 0.1};

I intended for [phi][xosc[f]] in h[xosc[f],f] to be 0. 
But referring the articles in Mathematica Stack exchange, It cause NDSolve::litarg error and need to correction that set [phi][xosc[f]] directly zero(to achive my intention). 
However, I have NO ideas to directly fix it. 
I just tried some correction. 
Firstly, using
With[{[phi][xosc[f]]=0},h[xosc[f],f]==0]

in the initial conditions but it dosen't work. 
Secondly, define h[x,f] to h[x] and make
\[Mu]HT2[x_, f_] := \[Mu]^2 - 
   M^2 Cos[\[Phi][x]/f + \[Alpha]0] + (m\[Phi][x, f]*
      ch*(1.12*10^(-3))^2)/x;
h[x_, f_] := 
  If[\[Mu]HT2[x, f] >= 0, 0, Sqrt[-\[Mu]HT2[x, f]/\[Lambda]]];

to
(* Relation between \[Phi] and h *)
\[Phi]hrel[t_, f_] := 
 Piecewise[{{0, \[Mu]^2 - 
       M^2 Cos[\[Phi][t]/f + \[Alpha]0] + (ch*
          m\[Phi][t, f]*(1.12*10^(-3))^2)/t >= 
      0}, {Sqrt[-(\[Mu]^2 - 
          M^2 Cos[\[Phi][t]/f + \[Alpha]0] + (ch*
             m\[Phi][t, f]*(1.12*10^(-3))^2)/t )/\[Lambda]], \[Mu]^2 -
        M^2 Cos[\[Phi][t]/f + \[Alpha]0] + (ch*
          m\[Phi][t, f]*(1.12*10^(-3))^2)/t < 0}}] == h[t]

and take it as additional differential equation in simultaneous relation. 
But it causes overdetermined system error below.
NDSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables, {h[t],\[Phi][t]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined.

After that, I found text related with DDE but it just make me more confused. 
So now I need advise or articles related with how can solve this problem decimate NDSolve::litarg error and overdetermined system error.
So I asking that advise or articles for referring to solving this problem - NDSolve::litarg error and overdetermined system error in a NDSolve for simultaneous differential equation.

Additionally I'm sorry for my rudeness that question formalism and the things that I missed.
I rarely write a question in Stack Exchange so I don't know how can I write good question text. 
Any advises are welcome.

Additional explanation
In a broad sense, the fields that my model intends to handle are two: $\phi$ and h.
Each of these fields follows the Equations of Motion (EOM) described below.
$$\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial_\phi V(x, f)}{m_\Phi(x, f)^2} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\gamma_h(x, f)}{m_\Phi(x, f)}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial_h V(x, f)}{m_\Phi(x, f)^2} = 0$$
Derivative potentials are given in the code (* Derivative Potentials for [Phi] and h *)
Specifically, $\phi$ exhibits motion without friction, while h shows motion with friction.
The friction corresponding to h, denoted as $\gamma_h$ depends on the value of h and has the following values.
$$\gamma_h(x, f) = \max\left(y_t^4 \cdot (h(x, f))^2 / \Gamma_{\text{th}}(x, f), \Gamma_{\text{th}}(x, f) \cdot (y_t)^2\right)$$
With
$$\Gamma_{\text{th}}(x, f) = 1.12 \times 10^{-4} \sqrt{m_{\Phi}(x, f)} \cdot x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
What I aim to do is a numerical analysis of the values of these two fields with respect to x.
Here, x is defined as the product of time t and mass $m_\phi$, and $m_\phi$ has the following values.
$$
m_{\Phi}(x, f) = \min \left( \left( \frac{\Lambda^2}{f} \left( \frac{\Lambda_c}{1.12 \times 10^{-3} x^{-\frac{1}{2}}} \right)^{\frac{11}{3}} \right)^{\frac{6}{17}}, \frac{\Lambda^2}{f} \right)
$$
It seems that the problem in my code arises from the definition of h.
h is correlated with $\phi$, and this relationship is as described below.
$$
h(x, f) =\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if } \mu^2 - M^2 \cos\left(\frac{\phi(x)}{f} + \alpha_0\right) + \frac{m_{\Phi}(x, f) \cdot ch \cdot (1.12 \times 10^{-3})^2}{x} \geq 0, \\
\sqrt{-\left(\mu^2 - M^2 \cos\left(\frac{\phi(x)}{f} + \alpha_0\right) + \frac{m_{\Phi}(x, f) \cdot ch \cdot (1.12 \times 10^{-3})^2}{x}\right)/\lambda} & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
The above is a rough description of my code.
All coefficients not mentioned above are fixed constants, and the use of the variable f in the code is to check the changes in the fields for about two to three different values of f.

I think litarg is because \[Phi][x] is not \[Phi][x, f1] or h[x, f1] is not h[x]. Probably should have the form F[x], since x is the only independent variable (it seems)

@Goofy
Thanks for your reply. I'll try it.

@chickenstick Nor in your previous post and here there is no any explanation of your model. From the other side your code looks very unlogic, so it is impossible to follow what do you try to compute.

@ALexTrounev I added some explanation about my model. However, I am not good at English, Markdown, and LaTeX, so it is hard to be sure if it is suitable for other people. I'm really sorry about it.

@chickenstick The last step is very unlogic. If $h$ correlated with $\phi$, then why $h$ is governed by own equation?

@AlexTrounev I totally missed specific concept. With your advice, I execute code review with my friend, and find some definition that I confused. Anyway, I truly thank for your advice, and it was really helpful for me. Thanks a lot!

@chickenstick If correlation is so important then we can solve equations in general form with 2 constant each and as a last step we can optimize 4 constant to follow correlation in the best way.  If you agree with this algorithm then I can help you with implementation.

@AlexTrounev Last time, I decided that discard phi-h relation in this cord. But right after, I recognize that the phi-h relation is so important in my model that it is impossible. So I need to keep that relation in my cord, but I have no idea about implementation. Its so hard to imagine that working process of your algorithm because lack of my abilities, however I need your help because the important thing is execute numerical analysis keep up with phi-h correlation.

@AlexTrounev Anyway, I truly assure that any advise from you is helpful for me. If you have time, please give me some advise based on your algorithm.
